# SharePoint listitem properties get lost after update via JS & CSOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint, csom

On my SharePoint there is a website where a single list-item is loaded based on a user's selection with JavaScript and CSOM. This list item has a total of ~60 properties defined in it's list definition.

In HTML input fields the user can modify most of the properties after jQuery filled in the loaded properties to their corresponding input fields. When the "save" button is pressed, the properties are collected from the inputs via jQuery and put into a simple JS-object (`itemProps`):

```
var itemprops = {
    'foo': $('#foo-input').val(),
    'bar': $('#bar-input').val()
}
```

Then, the following function gets called:

```
function updateListItem(itemProps, onItemAdded, onItemError) {
    var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle('ListTitle');
    var listItem = list.getItemById(id);
    for (var propName in itemProps) {
        if (itemProps.hasOwnProperty(propName)) {
            listItem.set_item(propName, itemProps[propName]);
        }
    }
    listItem.update();
    context.executeQueryAsync(
        function() {
            onItemAdded(listItem);
        },
        onItemError
    );
}
```

Debugging shows me, that the data in `itemProps` are valid. But *sometimes* (I can't reproduce that effect deterministically) some properties get lost and when I look at the list item in the list on the SharePoint some of the properties are empty, as if itemProps had `null` or `""` associated to that property. When I first tried to debug this I simply created an item and saved it (correctly, with all properties) and then loaded and saved it again without modification but some properties got lost.
Other properties get updated correctly and sometimes this doesn't happen at all.

Is there any way to make sure this effect does't occur or at least to detect it and retry updating the data, before the user's inputs get lost?

Answer (score 0):

I notice you're **not** invoking `context.load(listItem)` before calling `context.executeQueryAsync()` which might cause issues with the `listItem` object's values being stale or dehydrated.

The code in your question looks like it should still be *setting* the specified values correctly on the list item, although there may be some code later on (such as in the `onItemAdded` function) that's running into false assumptions or subtle data differences from the inadequately loaded list item.